# JavaScript/JQuery form validation runs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function I am in the middle of converting to JQuery that checks a form before submission.

```
function CheckRegistrationDetails(userId) {



    var ddl = document.getElementById('<%= cboDestination.ClientID %>');
    var toId = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;


    if (toId === "0") {
        $("#<%= lblCheckMessage.ClientID %>").html("Please the area you wish to register your items.");
        return false;}
    var u1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtItem1.ClientID %>').value.replace(/,/g, "");
    var u2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtItem2.ClientID %>').value.replace(/,/g, "");
    var u3 = document.getElementById('<%= txtItem3.ClientID %>').value.replace(/,/g, "");
    var u4 = document.getElementById('<%= txtItem4.ClientID %>').value.replace(/,/g, "");
    var u5 = document.getElementById('<%= txtItem5.ClientID %>').value.replace(/,/g, "");
    if (i1 === "") {
        i1 = "0";
    }
    if (i2 === "") {
        i2 = "0";
    }
    if (i3 === "") {
        i3 = "0";
    }
    if (i4 === "") {
        i4 = "0";
    }
    if (i5 === "") {
        i5 = "0";
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Register.aspx/RegisterItems",
        data: "{userId: " + userId + ", toLocationId: " + toId + ", item1: " + i1 + ", item2: " + i2 + ", item3: " + i3 + ", item4: " + i4 + ", item5: " + i5 + "}",
        success: function (response) {

            if (response.d === 1) {
                $("#<%= lblCheckMessage.ClientID %>").html("You are trying to register more items than you have");
                alert("false");
                return false;
                                }
            if (response.d === 0) {
                $("#<%= lblCheckMessage.ClientID %>").html("You do not have enough credits to register these items!");
                alert("false");
                return false;
            }
            if (response.d === 2) {
                alert(confirm("Are you sure you dont want to register all your items?"));
                return confirm("Are you sure you dont want to register all your items?");
            }
            alert("true");
            return true;

        },
        fail: function () {
            alert("false fail");
            return false;
        }

    });
    alert("false default");
    return false;
}
```

And the button hookup

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    cmdMakeRegistration.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return CheckRegistrationDetails(" + userToken.UserId + ");");
}
```

When I try to submit a valid form I get two `alert` boxes.  The first is `false default` the second is `true`.  The form doesn't submit.

I am stuck as to why I am getting two alerts

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an ajax request that succeeds, generating the second alert (comes in later), but there's a rogue (*And not the pretty looking, don't touch me, Rogue from X-men*) alert at the bottom of the validator:

`alert("false default");`

Your code always returns `false` thus prohibiting the form from being sent, however the Ajax call is sent and also succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the response, love the humor!  If I remove the `alert("false default");` I get a warning saying not all code paths return a value but the form does now submit BUT and its a big but, if I try to submit an invalid form I get the alert("false"); but the page submits.

Comment: The problem is that you are submitting twice. One time via Ajax and secondly through a normal submit, however, a normal submit should refresh the page.

Comment: Ok so I am better off putting my web methods in a separate page?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, what do you exactly expect from this code?

Comment: Just to validate the form data and prevent a postback if it fails.  The web method makes a call to the database to validate the data then returns an integer to denote the result.

Comment: Ok, I think what you want isn't possible. The ajax request (webmethod) is asynchronous and returns back when the original validator is already done. So you can't use that to return a value to the function.

Comment: So I am chasing my own tail with this.  No wonder I can get it to do what I want.  I hate front end development. lol  thanks